# Error: "module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping"

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Please help me out, I have been trying to resolve this error from a long time.

when i restart Apache and type `:sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -t`, I get an output like:

```
[Fri Aug 24 17:02:58 2012] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK
```

What is going wrong?

I have checked the `wsgi.load` file in `etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. It loads the `mod_wsgi.so` only once and I have installed `libapache-mod-wsgi` from the source.

Comment: Duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120057/module-wsgi-module-is-already-loaded-skipping

Comment: Have you looked at your configuration and verified that you aren't loading the module twice in the conf files, as suggested by @GrahamDumpleton's answer on the question he linked?

Comment: Look for the module's name anywhere in the Apache directory: `find /etc/apache2 |xargs grep -s -i wsgi`

Answer (score 2):

You are likely loading the module multiple times. Check in your conf.d directory.
`grep LoadModule /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf` and see what modules each config are attempting to load.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading those modules more than once. Try a search and comment or delete duplicate lines:

**In Centos/ RHEL:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/httpd/*   
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

In this case I commented out line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` so all SSL stuff live in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Same for `mod_wsgi`

```
grep mod_wsgi -rI /etc/httpd/*
```

**In Debian/ Ubuntu:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/apache2/*
```